# Does PHP controls Multitasking?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and will like to develop a mobile app that interacts with the server (By putting and pulling datas from the server). Initially I was using Java, but finacial issues I decided to use PHP because getting domain that uses java is expensive.

My question is that does PHP controls multitasking ? reason been that since I will have thousands of users connected to my server probably the same. I llok forward for your answers Thanks

Comment: why did u tagged it in java.?

Comment: This may help you http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-multitask/

Answer (score 1):

How should PHP have control over multitasking?

PHP interprets a PHP-Script to one point in time when a http-Request occurs on the Script.

Comment: additionally I may bring up, that, in PHP a script can include other scripts, and there may also be a call by a cronjob from the local system. But bewar: there is a timeout defined in php.ini (maybe 30 seconds) after that a script is stopped automatically.

Comment: The time limit is easy enough to manipulate, though: `set_time_limit(600)`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not do multi-threading. It's a single-process-execution kind of scripting language.

However, when set up as a server-side language, it's usually paired up with a HTTP server like Apache, IIS or Nginx, who manage several child processes to handle multiple requests. - If you set it up like a normal server-side language, on top of one of those HTTP servers, you will have no problems handling a lot of parallel traffic.

Comment: I wouldn't say "no problem", but yes, the web server is the part that handles several threads.

Comment: @deceze, Why would you not say that? By default, even a standard Apache-PHP install from a basic Linux repo can easily handle mid-sized website traffic. (Assuming the PHP code is reasonably well written.)

Comment: Exactly, *"if well written"* is the crux... ;)

Comment: I find it depressing to operate on the opposite assumption :)

Comment: Fellas thanks for the information. So all I should focus on is the script while the server handles the rest. Thanks once again